# TV show about 4 people who gain elemental powers (earth, air, fire, ice) and fight evil

Tags: story-identification, tv, animation

I can't remember much, but these four  animated people find a castle and they gain elemental powers.

They then find this girl who tells them to guard a weird looking blue orb. The villains then get to the orb but the orb breaks. The pieces of the orb are then lost and they have to go find the pieces.

I would be very grateful if you guys can find out what this is. I think it was made between 2019-2010.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you mean 2009-2010?

Comment: Was this 2D or 3D animation? Also, can you describe the appearance of any of the characters? (Sex, hair colour, and things like that.)

Comment: captain planet?